# Export all databases with mongoexport

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

In my app, I'm creating a new database for every user. So I have many databases currently. I need to back up them. But I couldn't find a way to export all databases and collections at the same time with `mongoexport`

Do anyone have solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using root user and password.

```
./mongodump --uri="mongodb://rootUser:rootPassword@localhost:27017/?authSource=admin"
```

This will create a dump folder.

For restoring ensure that your current directory contains that dump folder then.

```
./mongorestore -h localhost -p 27017 -u rootUser:rootPassword -p rootPassword
```

Comment: well, this is working but exports as bson format. is it possible to get all databases as json?

Comment: `mongodump` only outputs bson format. Maybe you can use `bsondump --pretty ./dump/db/collection.bson` to convert output to json. I tried out `mongoexport`, it requires you to specify the collection to export, so you can't export all dbs using it.
If you are worried about space then you can also add `--gzip` to `mongodump`.